# get array of waypoints with google map api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

Hello I can dynamically add autocompletion adresse text input but I don't know how to convert those adresse to an array of longitudes and latitudes, I would like to have a set of wayspoints to put on my map but I have no idea how to do it and i am newbie in javascript and angular js :

html:

```
<div ng-show="content == 'first'" ng-app="angularjs-starter" class="form-group" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  [<span ng-repeat="input in inputs">"{{input.value}}"</span>]
  <label class="control-label">tournee</label>
  <div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
    <!-- autocompletion adresse inputs-->
    <input google-place type="text" ng-model="input.value" />
    <button ng-click="removeInput($index)">Remove</button>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="addInput()">add input</button>
</div>
```

angular script

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.inputs = [];
  $scope.addInput = function() {
    $scope.inputs.push({
      value: ''
    });

  }

  $scope.removeInput = function(index) {
    $scope.inputs.splice(index, 1);
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a object and add to one array .

```
var arrayLatitudes = [];

var lat = 41;//number example
var lng = 40;//number example

var lngLat = {
    'lat':lat,
    'lng':lng
}

arrayLatitudes.push(lngLat);
```

Now you can create a Markers in the MAP with a for with the ArrayLatitudes.

Comment: thanks but I still have the pb of getting the latitude and the longitude from an adresse